# Nginx server keeps serving Debian main page

Tags: nginx, debian, apache2, go

I am trying to set up a simple custom website. I have built a simple server using Golang and the Gin-gonic framework. My Go server is as follows:

```
func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.GET("/", ServeMainPage)
        r.GET("/icons/openlogo-75.png", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.File("favicon.ico")
        })
        r.GET("/episode/:id", ServeEpisode)
        r.GET("styles/style.css", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.File("styles/style.css")
        })
        r.GET("scripts/main.js", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.File("scripts/main.js")
        })
        r.GET("favicon.ico", func(c *gin.Context) {
                c.File("favicon.ico")
        })
        r.Run()
}

func ServeMainPage(c *gin.Context) {
        c.File("index.html")
}

func ServeEpisode(c *gin.Context) {
        episodeID := c.Param("id")
        filepath := "AudioFiles/" + episodeID + ".mp3"
        c.File(filepath)
}
```

Because this process cannot access port 80 (it runs on :8080), and because I am trying to develop my skills, I have attempted to set-up an nginx server to act as a reverse proxy. My nginx server has the following conf, which is the default,

```
http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and I followed the tutorial [here](https://eladnava.com/binding-nodejs-port-80-using-nginx/) to have it forward things to my Golang app by adding the following to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/ro` and symbolic linking that to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ro`.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name running-oaks.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        }
}
```

If I use curl on my local PC to access my server, I get the index.html page I would like it to server. My curl command is simply `curl http://123.123.123.123`, where `123.123.123.123` is replaced by the actual IP of my remote server.

However attempting to access this same IP address with my web browser simply shows me the default Apache for Debian page. I uninstalled apache before setting up nginx in order to *hopefully* avoid conflicts. In both the curl case and the browser case, I can see that my Golang app is receiving the requests and returning a status 200.

So why does my browser keep showing me the debian page?

I have also changed `/var/www/index.html` to be the default nginx page, although that hasn't fixed it either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your request doesn't match your server block, but does match the default server block.

You have:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name running-oaks.com;
```

Which will match any request coming in on port 80 with the Hostname "running-oaks.com".

Out of the box, Ubuntu includes an already enabled site file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` which is a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. This is the site definition that provides the Debian main page.

In this config file, there's a server block that starts like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

This block has no server_name, but does have the `default_server` directive. This means that any request coming on port 80 that doesn't match another server block should use this server block.

**Since your request is using the direct IP and not the hostname that you specified on the server_name directive, your request matches the default server instead of your own.**

To fix this, you could delete the symlink at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and add the `default_server` directive to your listen line. Remember to restart Nginx after doing this.

(Adding the default_server is redundant because if there is only one server it defaults to being the default, but it's better to be explicit.)